# Database join query with three tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, drupal-7

**Here Iam trying to connect three tables so that i can get my desired out put**

*Drupal 7 db select*

```
function abc($Incharge) {
   $res= db_select('node', 'n')
 ->Join('aa', 'f', 'f.id = n.nid')
 ->Join('bb', 'd', 'd.id = f.entity_id');
 return $total_res = $res ->condition('n.type', 'ram')
   ->condition('d.target_id',$Incharge)
   ->condition('n.status', 1)
   ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
   ->orderBy('n.title', 'ASC')
   ->execute()->fetchAllKeyed();


}
```

But i am facing a issue

> Fatal error: Call to a member function Join() on string in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/transgenic/sites/all/modules/report_system/report_system.module
>   on line 735

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation (https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/joins)

> The return value of a join method is the alias of the table that was
>   assigned

And it also states -

> Joins cannot be chained, so they have to be called separately (see
>   Chaining). If you are chaining multiple functions together do it like
>   this:

So you have to do something like...

```
function abc($Incharge) {
   $res= db_select('node', 'n');
   $res->Join('aa', 'f', 'f.id = n.nid');
   $res->Join('bb', 'd', 'd.id = f.entity_id');
   return $total_res = $res ->condition('n.type', 'ram')
       ->condition('d.target_id',$Incharge)
       ->condition('n.status', 1)
       ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
       ->orderBy('n.title', 'ASC')
       ->execute()->fetchAllKeyed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know more about drupal i found solution like this hope it will help you .

`SelectQuery::join(), SelectQuery::leftJoin()` etc. don't return the query (they return the alias to the created JOIN), so they can't be chained.

Just separate your code out like this:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('l')
  ->fields('s', array('stamp', 'message'))
  ->orderBy('`order`', 'ASC');

$query->Join('aa', 'f', 'f.id = n.nid');

$result = $query->execute();
```